# not pushing elements in forEach statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object:

[image]

This is the function I use to loop through the object:

```
function getAllUsersKeys(user){

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var tokens = []

    user.forEach(function(user) {
            admin.database().ref(`/FAVORITES/${user.key}`).orderByKey().once('value').then((favShops) => {
            favShops.forEach((shop)=>{
                if(shop.key==saledata.store_id){    //if store that activated sale if found under users list under /FAVORITES

                    admin.database().ref(`/FAVORITES/${user.key}/token`).orderByKey().once('value').then((token) => {
                        //console.log(token.val().id);
                        tokens.push(token.val().id);                
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })
    resolve(tokens);
    })

    return promise;
}
```

the console message will print out the "id" under selected token.

```
//console.log(token.val().id);
```

but when I push this "id" into the array called *tokens* nothing appears.

```
tokens.push(token.val().id);
```

Basically what I want this method to do is return an array with a selected amount of "id".

Please help me optimise my code. Right now it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are resolving your getAllUserKeys promise before the firebase promises are resolved. The reason your console.log works is because it waits until your firebase lookup is done before logging. When you `resolve(tokens)`, the promises that fill that array haven't resolved yet.

You would need to make sure that all of your firebase promises have resolved before you `resolve(tokens)`.

UPDATE:

I'm not easily able to test this, so it likely won't work first try.

```
function getAllUserKeys(user) {
  return Promise.all(user.map(user => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/FAVORITES/${user.key}`).orderByKey().once('value');
  })).then(favShops => {
    return Promise.all(favShops.filter(shop => {
      if(shop.key === saledata.store_id) { 
        return admin.database().ref(`/FAVORITES/${user.key}/token`).orderByKey().once('value');
      }
      return false;
    }))
  }).then(tokens => {
    return tokens.map(token.val().id);
  })
}
```

This is an example of how you would chain promises.

1. Convert an array of users into and array of promises from firebase, this will resolve to favShops.
2. In the `then` method you will get the result of the promise all, which should be an array of favShops.
3. Take the favShops and filter out only the shops that match the saledata.store_id, returning promises that will be resolve by the firebase api.
4. Once all the filtered shops promises have resolved you will take the array of tokens and convert them into an array of ids.
5. Use `getAllUserKeys().then(tokens => {})` where tokens should be an array of ids.

Comment: im having tough time trying to debug code I dont fully understand " return Promise.all(users.map(user => {"where is this users coming from, you didn't input anything in your parameters....

Comment: return admin.database().ref(`/FAVORITES/${user.key}`).orderByKey().once('value');                          what datatype is returned in this line of code????? when i try testing it out i get back errors, im a bit of a noob

Comment: i get this error wtih the above code:       TypeError: users.map is not a function at getAllUserKeys (/user_code/index.js:240:30) at admin.database.ref.orderByKey.once.then (/user_code/index.js:126:9) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: Ok, well the code you provided takes in some variable called user and then does a forEach on it. I actually don't know why you are doing that. I was assuming that `user` was some array. If you only pass in one user then the code would be a bit different, even more simple. Can I the code that uses this getAllUserKeys(user) function?

Comment: i just preformed the task i needed to do in the last foreach call, without returning the result...thanks for putting up